# Can't put LinearLayout to the bottom of page android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I want to make a chat layout. I want to put Edittext and Button on the bottom of the screen. I already tried using gravity : bottom and alignParentBottom : true, but it doesn't give any effect about that.

This is my code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".chat">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friendChat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Nama"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/starbuck"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/friendChat"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/friendChatContainer"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friendChatContent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="haloooo"
                android:background="@color/starbuck"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/friendChatContainer"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/myChat"
            >
             <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="haloooo"
                android:background="@color/starbuck"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myChat"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Write a message"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:text="" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sendChat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/send"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what it looks like with that code :
[image: Layout]

The EditText and ImageButton supposed on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: It should be easy: would `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` work if added to the LinearLayout with id of myChat?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify basic structure of layout file, just modify two places as the following comments:

```
...
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myChat"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  //add this line
            android:gravity="bottom">
    <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Write a message"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:text="" />
    <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sendChat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" //delete this line
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
</LinearLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a RelativeLayout inside of your ConstraintLayout.

Firstly I suggest you use either the Relative Layout or the ConstraintLayout.

I give you an example for the ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".chat">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friendChat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Nama"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/starbuck"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/friendChat"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/friendChatContainer"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/friendChat">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friendChatContent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="haloooo"
                android:background="@color/starbuck"

                />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myChat"
            android:gravity="bottom"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Write a message"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:text="" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sendChat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/send"/>


        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This Framework should work for you accordingly. I deleted the one Textview, but you can edit it if you like.
You do not have to put it into another layout aswell. You can just use the `android:constraint...` in the textview itself.

With best regards

Comment: I would appreciate if you could accept my answer if it suits your needs!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your Bottom LinearLayout and remove `android:layout_gravity="center"` from send button. The final code is below.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".chat">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friendChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Nama"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/starbuck"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/friendChat"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/friendChatContainer"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friendChatContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="haloooo"
            android:background="@color/starbuck"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/friendChatContainer"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/myChat"
        >
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="haloooo"
            android:background="@color/starbuck"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myChat"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Write a message"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendChat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/send"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please avoid if any resource name is changed